# How to wait for completion of an animation chain and an ajax call with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very confused by the Promise and Deferred aspect of jQuery. I'm trying to wait for the second animation in a chain of two sequential animations as well as an ajax call to finish before doing something else (showing the result of the ajax call).

If it was just one animation, or even a bunch of animations happening concurrently, I know that I can do something like this:

```
var animPromise = $('#el').fadeIn().promise();
var ajaxPromise = $.ajax({...}).promise();
$.when(animPromise, ajaxPromise).done(function() {...});
```

or...

```
var animPromises = $('.elements').fadeIn().promise();
var ajaxPromise = $.ajax({...}).promise();
$.when(animPromises, ajaxPromise).done(function() {...});
```

...but I don't understand how to get a promise to the last animation without triggering it e.g.

```
$('#underlay').fadeIn(function() {
    $('#dialog').fadeIn(); // I need a promise for this
});
var ajaxPromise = $.ajax({...}).promise();
```

Both the ajax call and the `#dialog` are more or less equally likely to finish first. So basically, I don't want to load my ajax response into the dialog until the dialog animation has completed, but I want the benefit of kicking off the ajax request while the animation is running.

**I'm limited to jQuery 1.6**

After initially trying this solution, I was getting a null pointer on the call to `promise()`:

```
var ajaxTask = null;
$('#underlay').fadeIn({
    duration: 200,
    start: function() {
        ajaxTask = $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#dialog').fadeIn(300, function() {
            ajaxTask.promise().then(function() {
                callback( JSON.parse(ajaxTask.responseText) );
            });
        });
    }
});
```

It's working fine now with something like this:

```
var ajaxTask = $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
var ajaxPromise = ajaxTask.promise();

$('#underlay').fadeIn(200, function() {
    $('#dialog').fadeIn(300, function() {
        ajaxPromise.then(function() {
            callback( JSON.parse(ajaxTask.responseText) );
        });
    });
});
```

...but I'm concerned about the null pointer in the first example above. Is there still a possibility in the second working example that `ajaxPromise` could be uninitialized or something by the time it gets to `then`?

Or is it safe because the call to `promise()` is sychronous and the `ajaxTask` and `ajaxPromise` objects are guaranteed to be initialized before the animations start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Both the ajax call and the #dialog are more or less equally likely to
>   finish first. So basically, I don't want to load my ajax response into
>   the dialog until the dialog animation has completed, but I want the
>   benefit of kicking off the ajax request while the animation is
>   running.

Try using `start` function at `#underlay` to call `$.ajax()` , at `#underlay` `complete` call `#dialog` `.fadeIn()` , at `#dialog` `.fadeIn()` `done` process `$.ajax()` response

```js
var ajaxPromise;
$("#underlay").fadeIn({  
  // called when `#underlay` `.fadeIn()` starts
  start: function() {
    // start asynchronous process
    ajaxPromise = $.Deferred(function(d) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        d.resolve("complete")
      }, Math.random() * 2000)
    }).promise();
  },
  complete: function() {
    $("#dialog").fadeIn({
      // called when `#dialog` `.fadeIn()` animation completes
      done: function() {
        // `this` : `#dialog`
        el = $(this);
        // process asynchronous result
        ajaxPromise.then(function(data) {
          // do stuff with ajax response
          el.after(data)                
          }
          // handle ajax errors
          , function err(err) {
            console.log(err)
          })
      }
    }); // I need a promise for this
  }
});
```

```css
#underlay,
#dialog {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="underlay">underlay</div>
<div id="dialog">dialog</div>
```

Comment: But I want to start the ajax request at the same time as the #underlay animation

Comment: @RTF Use `start` function at `$('#underlay').fadeIn({start:function(){}})` , see updated post

Comment: I ended up doing something slightly different. I kicked off the ajax request before starting the first animation. So I didn't need the `start` function, but I still used `ajaxPromise.then` in the final animation callback. Works great, thanks buddy!

Comment: What's the deal with the `$.Deferred` call in the `start` function, and the random timeout?

Comment: @RTF _"What's the deal with the $.Deferred call in the start function, and the random timeout?"_ Simulating an `$.ajax()` request to demonstrate process at stacksnippets

Comment: I refactored my code to end up being something much closer to your answer, but initially I was getting a null pointer on the jqxhr object returned from the $.ajax call... I think I've fixed it but I'm still concerned... I'll just update my post if that's alright

Comment: _"was getting a null pointer on the jqxhr object returned from the $.ajax call"_ Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Can you just take a look at my update first, if it's not making any sense I'll see if I can reproduce

Comment: There should not be a "null pointer" , `$.ajax()` is called before animation starts  and is properly declared as variable `ajaxPromise` . Why is `ajaxTask` used within `.then()` ? instead of `ajaxPromise` ? Or , using returned `arguments` from `ajaxPromise` ? , e.g., `ajaxPromise.then(function(data) {
            callback( JSON.parse(data) );
        });` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use call back functions,

```
$('#underlay').fadeIn('slow', functioin(){

//executes after fadeIn

});
```

Comment: I know that, but my question is how do I immediately get a promise to an animation in the callback(s)?